# How to get the record deletion date in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I need to delete the a specific student from *stdnt* table and insert that students data into a new table *stdnt_log* including the 'leaving_date' field, which would be the record's deletion date

```
sql = "INSERT INTO stdnt_log SELECT rollno, name, grade, leaving_date FROM stdnt WHERE rollno = ?";

sql = "DELETE FROM stdnt WHERE rollno = ?";
```

Comment: You can use `sysdate`.  This should be done in a trigger, not at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler option - if you can/want to apply it - is to alter the `stdnt` table and add another column: `deactivation_date`:

```
alter table stdnt add deactivation_date date;
```

Once someone gets *deactivated*, just update that column:

```
update stdnt set 
  deactivation_date = sysdate
  where student_id = some_value;
```

Active students would then be

```
select * from stdnt where deactivation_date is null;
```

Simpler to implement, easier to maintain. Drawback? Table will be larger and larger, but  hey, this is Oracle, it handles *zillions* of rows without problems.